# How can I find out what thread is using CPU in my android application

Tags: android, cpu

If I run top on my dev android device I can see that when my app in is the background it uses .6% cpu, if I bring it to the foreground it uses 5-6% of the cpu. The problem is, it's not doing anything. There's no services running, there's no background threads, it's just waiting for the user to click a button.

Is there a way in adt or via some other tool to find out which thread is eating the cpu so I can get an idea where to start looking for problems?

Comment: Run a profiler and see whats being called.  There's one included with Eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and it's even free. it is called [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) and is part of the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

[image]

Connect your device via USB, start off your app, and then open DDMS view and you will be able quickly find your CPU intensive thread.

Note that it's a good practice to give human readable names to the threads spawned by your program. Your users will never these names, but it will make thread debugging/profiling simpler:

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("DB-Access-Thread");
```

Comment: silly me, I use ddms, but it never occurred to me to look for cpu usage. Thanks.

Comment: Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. The features that you could use through the Android Device Monitor have been embedded in Android Studio now.

Source:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

That said it looks like you can still start it using: android-sdk/tools/monitor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in profiler in Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler

[image: Android Studio CPU profiler]

You can also run `adb shell top` but this will only give you CPU and MEM usage per process not thread.

For more info check out this Google I/O presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5V9ZSL0BsM&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIInFRc3M44HUTQc3b_YJ4-Y&index=135